# Display online and offline (e.g. airplane) mode in an Ember.js App

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Can an Ember app be aware of the network status? If yes: How can I get the information if the app has access to the internet or not? I'd like to switch GUI elements depending on the network accessibility.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  Status:
  {{#if isOffline}}
    Offline
  {{else}}
    Online
  {{/if}}
  <hr>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*The short:*

Since you asked for an **ember app** I've dedicated some time to provide an acceptable answer. Here is the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egevih/42/edit).

*The long:*

I add here some of the code, for the complete code please look at the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egevih/42/edit) provided.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  Status:
  {{#if App.isOffline}}
    <span class="offline">Offline</span>
  {{else}}
    <span class="online">Online</span>
  {{/if}}
  <hr>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
</script>
```

> Note: I've used the js lib [heyoffline.js](https://github.com/oskarkrawczyk/heyoffline.js) since it's one of the best around IMO.
>   I've also overriden the functions that show a modal window (the lib show's per default a modal window when offline occurs, but since we are going to control it trough our ember app it's not needed), to get it back just remove the prototype overiddes.

**app.js**

```
// overrides to not show the default modal window, to get it back just remove this overrides
Heyoffline.prototype.showMessage = function() {
  //this.createElements();
  if (this.options.onOnline) {
    return this.options.onOnline.call(this);
  }
};

Heyoffline.prototype.hideMessage = function(event) {
  if (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  //this.destroyElements();
  if (this.options.onOffline) {
    return this.options.onOffline.call(this);
  }
};


//ember app
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  isOffline: false,
  service: null,
  ready: function(){
    this.set('service', App.HeyOffline.create());
  }
});

// Heyoffline wrapper
App.HeyOffline = Ember.Object.extend({
  service: null,
  init: function(){
    // heyoffline instantiation
    this.set('service', new Heyoffline());
    // hook into the two important events
    this.set('service.options.onOnline', this.offline);
    this.set('service.options.onOffline', this.online);
  },
  online: function(){
    App.set('isOffline', false);
    console.log("online");
  },
  offline: function(){
    App.set('isOffline', true);
    console.log("offline");
  }
 });

 App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});
```

To test that it works, load the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/egevih/42/edit) and go offline, see how the Status in the template changes, go back online to see it change again.

With this setup in place you should get the online/offline status of the browser the ember way, enjoy :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

With HTML5, you can check the `navigator.onLine` boolean status.

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    // Online
} else {
    // Offline
}
```

If you need to listen for going offline or online, you can handle the `offline` and `online` events of `window`. Note that in IE, the event is raised for `document.body`, not `window`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: How would I implement that in an Ember app?

Comment: @wintermeyer I'm really not sure - I've never worked with it. But whenever you need to know if the computer is online or not, just check the `navigator.onLine` value and do something based off that

Comment: @wintermeyer If you can explain exactly how you're using it with an Ember app, I could try to help. But it seems pretty straightforward - just check the property, or bind listeners to the specific events that detect offline/online

Comment: I added a simple Ember application. I'd like to change the status of this application depending of it being online/offline.